# Creating a new Dataframe from an existing one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-preprocessing

I have a Dataframe containing various medical measurements of different patients over a number of hours (in this example 2). For instance, the dataframe is something like this:

```
patientid  hour measurementx measurementy
 1          1    13.5         2030
 1          2    13.9         2013
 2          1    11.5         1890
 2          2    14.9         2009
```

Now, I need to construct a new Dataframe that basically groups all measurements for each patient, which would look like this:

```
patientid  hour measurementx measurementy  hour  measurementx measurementy
1          1    13.5         2030          2     13.9         2013
2          1    11.5         1890          2     14.9         2009
```

I'm quite new to Python and i have been struggling with this simple operation, I have been trying something like this, , trying to concatenate and empty Dataframe x_binary_compact with my data x_binary

```
old_id = 1
for row in x_binary.itertuples(index = False):
    new_id = row[0]
    if new_id == old_id:
        pd.concat((x_binary_compact, row), axis=1)
    else:
        old_id = new_id
        pd.concat((x_binary_compact), row, axis=0)
```

But i get an empty Dataframe as a result, so something is not right

Comment: Your expected output is unobtainable since a data frame cannot have duplicate column name.

Comment: Have a read through [the relevant section of the Pandas user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How make a dataframe in wide format creating new column names from the existing ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68393884/how-make-a-dataframe-in-wide-format-creating-new-column-names-from-the-existing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

s = '''patientid  hour measurementx measurementy
1          1    13.5         2030
1          2    13.9         2013
2          1    11.5         1890
2          2    14.9         2009'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep = "\s+")
df.pivot("patientid", "hour", ["hour", "measurementx", "measurementy"])
```

The result is shown below :

```
             hour      measurementx        measurementy
hour         1  2           1   2            1     2
patientid                       
1           1.0 2.0       13.5  13.9      2030.0  2013.0
2           1.0 2.0       11.5  14.9      1890.0  2009.0
```

Just make sure to rename the column names into unique values and reorder the columns will get your desire table.

```
new_names = []
for i in df1.columns :
    new_names.append(str(i[0])+str(i[1]))
df1.columns = new_names
df1.reset_index()[["patientid", "hour1", "measurementx1", "measurementy1", "hour2", "measurementx2", "measurementy2"]]
```

Output :

```
patientid   hour1   measurementx1   measurementy1   hour2   measurementx2   measurementy2
1            1.0         13.5          2030.0        2.0         13.9       2013.0
2            1.0         11.5          1890.0        2.0         14.9       2009.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'patientid': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                   'hour': [1, 2, 1, 2],
                   'measurementx': [13.5, 13.9, 11.5, 14.9],
                   'measurementy': [2030, 2013, 1890, 2009]})

df2 = df.set_index(['patientid', df.groupby('patientid').cumcount()+1]).unstack()
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel(1)
# sort columns in steps of 2, even first then odd.  If there are 3 for each patient id, would need step of 3, etc.
df2 = df2.iloc[:, list(np.arange(0, len(df2.columns), 2)) + list(np.arange(0, len(df2.columns)-1, 2)+1)]

df2
#Out: 
#           hour  measurementx  measurementy  hour  measurementx  measurementy
#patientid                                                                    
#1             1          13.5          2030     2          13.9          2013
#2             1          11.5          1890     2          14.9          2009
```

You can use `.reset_index()` at the end, if you want the `patientid` as a column.

Obviously, having multiple columns with the same name is not a great idea if you are then going to analyse it.  But if you are printing it, exporting to Excel etc. then this answer works.